# Module '"../node_modules/@types/d3"' has no exported member 'event'

Tags: typescript, d3.js, types, babeljs, typescript-typings

I have 2 pbiviz projects with all similar packages versions.

```
"dependencies": {
   "@babel/runtime": "7.6.0",
   "@babel/runtime-corejs2": "7.6.0",
   "@types/d3": "5.7.2",
   "d3": "5.12.0",
   "powerbi-visuals-utils-dataviewutils": "2.2.1",
   "powerbi-visuals-api": "~2.6.1",
   "core-js": "3.2.1"
}
```

The old project imports `event` perfectly from `d3`. But the new project is showing this error.

`Module '"../node_modules/@types/d3"' has no exported member 'event'.ts(2305)`

[image: Module '"../node_modules/@types/d3"' has no exported member 'event'.]

After unsuccessful at searching for solution and other attempts like deleting and running `npm i`, I just copy pasted the 'node_modules/@types' folder from old project to new project and it worked.

If anyone know what caused this problem and a proper solution, please share.

Comment: `d3.event` was removed from the main bundle as of version 6.0: https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/CHANGES.md#d3-selection. For more info see [*"Unable to get node datum on mouseover in D3 v6"*](/q/63693132).

Comment: @altocumulus But the d3 version is v5 itself. `"@types/d3": "5.7.2",
    "d3": "5.12.0"`

Comment: Can you do a `console.log(d3.version)` somewhere in your code?

Comment: Here is the output `5.12.0`

Comment: What's the output of `npm list` and `npm list -g` when run on the non-working project? Are you seeing the versions as defined in your `package.json`?

Comment: @altocumulus There are only 2 packages in common in both global and project's package that is tslint and typesript. `"tslint": "^5.18.0"` and `"typescript": "3.6.3"` in the project. And  `tslint@6.1.3` and `typescript@3.9.6` in global

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just updated both D3js and Types,

```
npm i d3@latest @types/d3@latest
```

This solved the issue. Now `event` is the first parameter of the event listener callback function.

Answer (score 2):

`event` is part of d3-selection and only exported in the `v1` of `@types/d3-selection`. Running `yarn list`/`npm list`, you'll see that `"@types/d3": "5.7.4"` dependency for d3-selection is `@types/d3-selection@*`, which is actually defaulted to `v2`.

[screenshot of @types/d3 dependency list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xRkn9.png)

Solution is to include `"@types/d3-selection": "^1.0.0"` in dependencies